# Reference for Cauchy-type identity

Tags: reference-request, cauchy-identity, harmonic-polynomials

For polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, the following inner product appears frequently in the literature of harmonic polynomials:
$$
\langle f,g \rangle = f(\partial/\partial x_1, \dots, \partial/\partial x_n) \cdot g(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mid_{x_1 =  \dots = x_n  = 0}.
$$
In `[Chains on Bruhat Order](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0502363.pdf)', the authors prove that two bases $\{f_\alpha\} $ and $\{g_\alpha\}$ (indexed by weak compositions) of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ are mutually orthogonal with respect to $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ if and only they satisfy the Cauchy-type identity
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n e^{x_iy_i} = \sum_\alpha f_\alpha(x_1,\dots,x_n) \cdot g_\alpha(y_1,\dots,y_n).
$$
They call the result "essentially well-known", with an attribution to an expository paper by Bergeron and Garsia "On certain spaces of harmonic polynomials" from 1993.
Can anyone point me to an earlier reference for this identity?